# How to use a jQuery UI widget inside another created using the widget factory

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, widget

I'm trying to create a simple jQuery UI widget that serves as an on/off switch. It's really nothing more than a radio button group. On its own it works fine, however if I have more than one of these widgets on a page the returned value is always the value of the last created instance.

I understand why this is - the change event tied to the buttonset references 'self' and this is set when an instance is created, but it really needs to point to the instance that created the radio buttons and the buttonset.

So my question is: how do I fix the change event function so it can call the value() function of my widget for the right widget instance?

I have a (crudely written) jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/38Qwy/

**Code:**

```
(function($) {

$.widget('custom.onoff', {
    options: {
        value: 0,
        captionOn: "on",
        captionOff: "off"
    },

    radios: {},

    _create: function() {
        this.oldValue = 2;

        var self = this,
        o = self.options,
        el = self.element,
        r = self.radios,
        htmlValue = el.html();
        el.html(''); // clear html content before appending elements
        var radOn = $('<input type="radio">').uniqueId().appendTo(el),
        radOnLabel = $('<label id="lab_' + radOn.attr('id')+'" for="' + radOn.attr('id') + '">' + o.captionOn + '</label>').appendTo(el),
        radOff = $('<input type="radio">').uniqueId().appendTo(el),
        radOffLabel = $('<label id="lab_' + radOff.attr('id')+'" for="' + radOff.attr('id') + '">' + o.captionOff + '</label>').appendTo(el);

        radOn.attr('name',radOn.attr('id'));
        radOff.attr('name',radOn.attr('id'));

        $(el).buttonset();

        this.radios.htmlValue = htmlValue;

        if(parseInt(htmlValue) == htmlValue) { // if the html content of the div is 0 or 1, use that to set or reset the switch
            if(htmlValue == 0 || htmlValue == 1)
                o.value = parseInt(htmlValue);
        }

        this.radios.radOn = '#' + radOn.attr('id');
        this.radios.radOff = '#' + radOff.attr('id');
        this.radios.radOnLabel = '#' + radOnLabel.attr('id');
        this.radios.radOffLabel = '#' + radOffLabel.attr('id');
        this.radios.name = radOn.attr('id');

        $('[name='+self.radios.name+']').change(function() {
            var val = $( self.radios.radOn ).is(':checked');
            var oldval = self.options.value == 1;
            if(val != oldval)
                self.value(val);
        });

        self.value(o.value);
    },

    destroy: function() {
        var self = this;
        var r = self._radios;
        var el = self.element;

        el.button('destroy');
        $(r.radOn).remove();
        $(r.radOff).remove();
        $(r.radOnLabel).remove();
        $(r.radOffLabel).remove();

        el.html(this.radios.htmlValue);
    },

    _setOption: function(option, value) {
        $.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply( this, arguments );

        switch (option) {
            case "captionOn":
                $(this.radios.radOnLabel).html(value);
                break;
            case "captionOff":
                $(this.radios.radOffLabel).html(value);
                break;
            case "value":
                this.value(value);
                break;
        }   
    },

    value: function( newValue ) {
        if ( newValue === undefined ) {
            return this.options.value;
        }

        if (newValue === false )
            newValue = 0;

        if (newValue === true )
            newValue = 1;

        this.options.value = newValue;
        this._refreshValue();
    },

    _refreshValue: function() {
        var value = this.options.value;

        if ( this.oldValue != value ) {
            this.oldValue = value;

            if(value == 1) {
                $(this.radios.radOn).prop('checked',true).button("refresh");
            } else {
                $(this.radios.radOff).prop('checked',true).button("refresh");
            }

            this._trigger( "change" );
        }
    }

}); // widget

})(jQuery);
```

**UPDATE:**
Problem solved, new jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/74B4w/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, all I needed to do was call my widget's change() function when the contained buttonset was changed. The change() function could then read the state of the 'on' radio button and store the new value, as well as triggering events.

```
this._container.buttonset().change(function() {
    this._change();
}.bind(this))
.appendTo(this.element);
```

Working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/74B4w/

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question posed in the title, like so: `$.widget( "custom.superDialog", $.ui.dialog, {} );` [Docs](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/extending-widgets/)

Now to look at your code...

Comment: Maybe I'm approaching it the wrong way. Could I maybe extend the original button plugin so that it creates the radio buttons and labels and runs buttonset()?